# Python - Thread, Sending 20 request - First to arrive, First to serve?

Tags: python, multithreading, request

So I was thinking to use some request to send etc 20 request to a site and the first one to serve a value from one of those site should use that value and continue my code basically. So whenever there is a value inside a String or whatever then just continue the code. However I got stuck. What I have done so far is that I have been able to send only one request:

```
my_key = load["MyKey"] # My own key for website.
website_key = webkey
url = webUrl

Myclient = MyClient(my_key)  
task = Task(url, website_key)
values = client.createTask(task)

value.join()
value = values.get_response()

print(value)
```

So basically with .join is searches for the value from the website and then return it as a get_response whenever its ready. However when I do this, It will only do one and then end.

And what I want to do is basically to send like etc 25 of them and then whenever hits the value first then end the other one and continue or end the program pretty much.

What would be the best solution for that?

Comment: check grequests

Comment: Oh damn, Looks awesome. However I need to do the code I provied above, It must be the same. Else I wont be able to get a value from my website. So I guess multi-thread and then throw like 25 threads etc into that Code and then whenever solves/finds the value, then print it/end?